# Process order for --skip-grant-tables mysqld

Tags: mysql, apache

I have a question about a scenario i currently have. generally the process should work but i can't seem to login successfully afterwards. either getting an incorrect username/password combination or an "unable to select Database" error when logging in with any credentials.

to skip forward a bit i have shutdown the mysql server on the machine and restarted it with the command

/etc/init.d/mysqld --skip-grant-tables

then logged in with mysql -u root -p

obviously this lets me in straight away as it skips the permissions check.

My goal is to change the password on a for a user on a table.

Currently there are three databases on the server we will call them as follows.

**INFORMATION_SCHEMA**

**mysql**

**gnb**

There is a table in **gnb** called **users** which has a username an password field. it has a single entry called **admin** under username which i want to change the password for as that is where the web server pulls the data from.

i have successfully changed the password for this particular user with the command

UPDATE users SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE username='admin';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

And 1 row is affected and i can visibly see the password hash change. also flushing privileges.

here's where i run into my problem....

once i have reset the password and restarted the mysql server in a normal mode i navigate back to the web server login and attempt to log in with the details that i now have.

i'm met with a **"unable to select database"** error message. 
i'm not sure if i have to do something prior to restarting the database? or do i also have to restart the apache web server? i have tried a mirage of different combinations of things but just can't seem to get it working. if i attempt to log in whilst still in --skip-grant-tables mode then i just get an invalid login attempt.

thanks in advance/

I'm stumped....

Comment: How did you get mysql1 and mysql2? Those are not valid system databases. The users table should be in a database named simply "mysql". I doubt anything else will work.

Comment: sorry was for arguments sake. their is a database called mysql and a database called gnb. mysql1 = mysql and msql2 = gnb

Comment: the login for the web server pulls the login details from gnb.users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the future.

second table was storing passwords in MD5.
update the row without using any password commands. simply a row update and update it with the MD5 hash of the password i was wishing to use.

web server then recognized the MD5 string as being the correct password and i was able to gain access.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a misunderstanding about how the MySQL authentication system works.

When an application (e.g. a PHP script) connects to MySQL, the user/password checks against the `mysql.users` table. It does not check any other table in another database, even if that database (gnb) is the database that contains your application's data.

The fact that you have a table called "users" in your gnb database has no bearing on the MySQL authentication system. Of course you can put any data you want into that table, but it won't be used by MySQL authentication.

You can change passwords with the [SET PASSWORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-password.html) command, or you can UPDATE the `mysql.users` table directly and then FLUSH PRIVILEGES.

Comment: I see your point, and mysql is not what i am trying to log into. i can set the root password for the mysql database fine, what i'm trying to achieve is a change in password not for mysql.user but for gnb.users which is where the web server pulls it's info from. it queries SELECT users = "username field" WHERE password = 'HASHED password" to authenticate for the webpage or something similar to that (can't remember)...

should of been more clear, sorry about that.

Comment: Can't help you any more without seeing the code. You seem to be using MySQL's builtin PASSWORD() function for application-level login, despite the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password) that says you should not do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bill. Unable to provide code as i am pentesting this machine, but having trouble getting the login. i did not build the database.